# The bus or car part that we stand on name

Tags: word-request

When we stand on the bus or a car, what is the part called that our feet comes in contact with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Floor

> 2a: the lower inside surface of a hollow structure

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floor

Comment: Note: in a ship it's the **deck**.

Answer (score 3):

In American English, this called the car or bus **floor**, and coverings for it are called [floor mats](https://www.amazon.com/Floor-Mats/b?ie=UTF8&node=318250011).